# How do I configure the maven findbugs reporting plugin to link bug patterns to the correct site?

Tags: maven, findbugs, find-sec-bugs

I use the Findbugs Maven plugin to generate a report for my projects that provides a summary of issues that Findbugs has found. I also use plugins such as the [find security bugs](http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/) plugin to find additional potential issues.

When I look at the generated site (an example can be found [here](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/examples/findbugs.html)), it has links to the site where it discusses details regarding the bug patterns it has flagged. But when I click on a link of a bug pattern from a findbugs plugin such as "find security bugs", it takes me to the findbugs website rather than the plugin's website.

Is there a configuration option where I can specify that a plugin's patterns can be found at a specific webpage?

Comment: What do you mean by `plugin's patterns can be found at a specific webpage`?

Comment: So if I used the find security bugs plugin for findbugs, it will list out patterns  that are described on this page[1]. But it will link to the main findbugs pattern description page. I think there should be a way to tell it to link find security bug patterns to the find security bug patterns description page.

[1] http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm